# bell was ringing OR rang

Tags: verbs

Replace the bold part with correct one:

1. The bell **was ringing and ringing** but no one picked up the phone.

(a) rang and rang                      (b) rang repeatedly (answer sheet)

(c) was ringing repeatedly (my answer) (d) No improvement

Why option C is incorrect here? B could also be a possible answer, but i don't see why C is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rang repeatedly* is the **most correct** answer in this situation. It seems the multiple choice answers you were provided were done in a way so that every sentence sounds correct to the English speaking ear, however (b) would be considered **most correct** because it achieves its purpose in the sentence in the least redundant/most concise manner possible.

I've spoken English all my life and *was ringing repeatedly* sounds correct, but *rang repeated* is the best way to say it, and is likely the most common way/sophisticated way to say that something *was ringing and ringing*

Answer (score 2):

This question is not really about what is correct or incorrect. It's about what is most appropriate or idiomatic. And while I would opt for (b) as the most likely answer, it's not the only correct answer. Much depends on the context.

(a) >The bell was ringing and ringing but no one picked up the phone.

This *past continuous* tense, which emphasises the continuous ringing of the bell by repetition, might well be used by someone telling a story. The speaker tries to keep the action alive by using a tense close to the historic present. It implies that the event is not yet over.

(b) >The bell rang and rang but no one picked up the phone.

The use of the *past tense* implies that the event is over. This a perfectly acceptable and correct sentence if not quite as neat as (b).

(c)>The bell was ringing repeatedly but no one picked up the phone.

Like (a) this sentence keeps the action alive if a speaker is giving a dramatic account of an event. It is also correct but most likely to be used in a specific context.

For example, it's the tense that a speaker might use to describe a fire, as in:

> The fire was burning fiercely but there was no sign of the fire brigade.